# What is causing the console error "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined at HTMLTableRowElement"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I am currently working on a Chrome extension. I am trying to make it so that if you hover over a  element, the background gets lighter and when you leave it, it goes back.

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/page.aspx") {
    tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        tr[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            tr[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #A9A9A9')
        });
        tr[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
            tr[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #808080')
        });
    };
};
```

Instead, it does nothing and when I check the console, I get twelve errors saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
    at HTMLTableRowElement", all for lines 5 and 8.
What is causing these errors?

**EDIT** I have to use setAttribute() to override current CSS that makes it impossible to use tr[i].style.backgroundColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, just losing reference to the desired table row. One option is to use the `this` keyword since the TR can reference itself from its event listener function.

```js
tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  tr[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #A9A9A9')
  });
  tr[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #808080')
  });
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Hi</td></tr>
  <tr><td>There</td></tr>
</table>
```